# CSS/HTML Custom Frame/Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to create custom enclosure of a div widget.

Below is the code that I have came up and I would like to add a custom frame/effect to it. Can it be done with HTML/CSS? Thanks for the help.

```
{<div class="container-fluid">
<section class="p-t-3 p-b-2" id="categories">
    <div class="categories">
        <div id="froala-editor">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <div>
                            <h3 style="display: inline-block;">
                                <br>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row center-block">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div class="category" style='background-image: url("");'>
                                <a class="category-link" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                                    <span class="category-content">
                                        <span class="category-title">Downtown</span>
                                        <span class="category-subtitle">
                                            <span class="btn btn-primary">View Listings</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>}
```

Comment: Do you mean a custom border?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal yeah. I'm not sure how to put a custom border to enclose this widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can make custom borders by using `border-image` property:**

Example:
To apply border on `.container-fluid`

```
.container-fluid {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/aDIDvOG021w/) 30 round;
}
```

You can replace the image with the image of your choice.

> Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/RwGYQgR

Comment: This is also the image that I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, so  you want a white border like that image.

Comment: Yes. I'll just figure out the image/widget size. This is just for plain frontend design.

Comment: This is the actual front end of the website that I am trying to have those settings applied. https://i.imgur.com/0l4luxK.png

Comment: Ok, let me see.

Comment: You are an angel. Thank you so much. I am a dummy for coding so you are helping me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/VwKGxXR

Comment: Sorry for the late.

Comment: No worries about the late response, Manas! I appreciate it. In that code that you've made, how can we add borders to each tile?

Comment: To add a border, add this `  border: 10px solid red;` to `.card` class.

Comment: If you want any other changes let me know

Comment: Also, I just want to ask if you know how to do it. I am actually using just plain rich text source code to apply these. Does the CSS style setting can be applied inside the html page?

Comment: yes, you make `<style></style>` inside the `<head>` tag and copy whole CSS section code from codepen and paste it into it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a bunch, Manas!

Answer (score 0):

To apply border on .container-fluid

```
.container-fluid {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: url() 30 round;
}
```

You can add an image with the image of your choice inside the url(). That'll help you to get more customized color or you can add solid color as:

```
.container-fluid {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-image: url() 30 round;
  border-color: coral;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Manas! Thank you so much. However, if I am using just plain source code editor from a rich text editor, how could I apply that container-fluid setting?

Comment: It's just a css class you should add in your css file. If this class already exist just edit  with these properties.